# buttons not visible in responsive layout

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design, responsive

The buttons are not visible in the responsive layout. In the responsive layout -

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

}

I am unable to see the "Register" and "Login" buttons.

app.component.html

```
<header class="topbar" [attr.data-navbarbg]="options.navbarbg" style="    background: #f07800;">
    <nav class="navbar top-navbar navbar-expand-md"
        [ngClass]="(options.navbarbg=='skin6')?'navbar-light':'navbar-dark'">
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- [attr.data-navbarbg]="options.navbarbg" -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="background:#f07800;"
            [ngbCollapse]="!isCollapsed">

            <app-navigation (toggleSidebar)="toggleSidebarType()" class="w-100"></app-navigation>
            <div (mouseover)="changeColorSignUp=true" (mouseout)="changeColorSignUp=false" style="width:11%">
                <span *ngIf="!changeColorSignUp"> <a [href]="signUpPath"
                        style="color:#0B3C6D;margin-right:2%;font-weight:bold;font-size:125%;">Register</a> </span>
                <span *ngIf="changeColorSignUp"> <a [href]="signUpPath"
                        style="color:white;margin-right:2%;font-weight:bold;font-size:125%;">Register</a> </span>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-right:3%">
                <div (mouseover)="changeColor=true" (mouseout)="changeColor=false">
                    <span *ngIf="!changeColor"> <a [href]="loginPath"
                            style="color:#0B3C6D;font-weight:bold;margin-right: 2%;font-size: 125%;">Login</a> </span>
                    <span *ngIf="changeColor"> <a [href]="loginPath"
                            style="color:white;font-weight:bold;margin-right: 2%;font-size: 125%;">Login</a> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">

    <!-- == CMS MainContent (BEGIN) == -->
    <div class="MainContent">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="title">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" id="mainDiv1Css" >
                    <div class="card_home wow zoomIn" id="card1Css" >
                       //code
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you expect them to hide when you have nothing in your media queries? or did you miss adding them here?

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1"

Comment: @Nithin ... means ?

Comment: ok, do you have only two menu or can have many?

Comment: this is happing due to `collapse` class.if you have only two menu then just remove it.

Comment: Yes solved. Thanks .

Comment: @Prakash. I want to know why due to collapse I was unable to see it in responsive ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200435/discussion-between-prakash-rajotiya-and-techdive).